# Unable to parse dates with an optional day part in Pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark data frame with string dates that may be either yyyyMM (e.g. 200802) or yyyyMMdd (e.g. 20080917). I am trying to parse these into dates. The function I am currently considering is [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html). Looking at the [datetime parsing patterns documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html), I should be able to use an optional section in square brackets. However, I cannot get this to work. Dates with a yyyy-MM or yyyy-MM-dd pattern do work with an optional section.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('200802', '2008-02', ), ('20080917', '2008-09-17', )], ['t', 't2'])
display(df
        .withColumn('fdate', F.to_date(F.col('t'), 'yyyyMM[dd]'))
        .withColumn('fdate2', F.to_date(F.col('t2'), 'yyyy-MM[-dd]'))
)
```

The output is:

| t | t2 | fdate | fdate2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200802 | 2008-02 | 2008-02-01 | 2008-02-01 |
| 20080917 | 2008-09-17 | null | 2008-09-17 |

You can see that the pattern with dashes correctly parses both date formats, but the strictly numeric pattern does not. Am I using this function incorrectly? Is there a way that I can parse these dates without using a UDF?

I am using Spark 3.5.0 in Databricks runtime 14.2.